# How to manage asynchronous mouse events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events

I have JavaScript code where:

- When the user presses the left mouse button, a `mousedown` event is fired, which triggers a call to function `OnMouseDown`.
- When the user releases the left mouse button, a `mouseup` event is fired, which triggers a call to function `OnMouseUp`.

The two events are fired asynchronously.

For example, the `mouseup` event can be fired immediately after the `mousedown` event is fired (short mouse click), before the `OnMouseDown` ends. (Figure1)

I want to process the events sequentially, where the function `OnMouseUp` will only start after `OnMouseDown` ends.

I can achieve this by preventing the `mouseup` event from firing until after `OnMouseDown` ends (by calling `removeEventListener('mouseup', OnMouseUp)` when `OnMouseDown` begins) (`Figure2`)

But then I may lose a `mouseup` event altogether (`Figure3`)

Figure3 - `mouseup` event is lost

I am looking for a way to insure that

- a `mouseup` event after a `mousedown` event is not lost, and
- the `OnMouseUp` function begins after `OnMouseDown` ends.

[image: Event timing chart]
How can I achieve this?

The following code example demonstrates the problem:

```js
function sleep1 () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve("Finished sleeping");
    }, 2000);
  });
}

// The mousedown event is fired when a pointing device button (usually a mouse button) is pressed on an element.
document.addEventListener('mousedown', async function(e) {
    console.log('BEG OnMouseDown');
  let retval = await sleep1();
  console.log('retval: ', retval);
    console.log('END OnMouseDown');
});


// The mouseup event is fired when a pointing device button (usually a mouse button) is released over an element.
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    console.log('BEG OnMouseUp');
    console.log('END OnMouseUp');
});
```

Clicking on the left mouse button and releasing results in the following printout, which shows that the function OnMouseUp ends before the function OnMouseDown ends, which fits figure1.

```
BEG OnMouseDown
BEG OnMouseUp
END OnMouseUp
Inside OnMouseDown:  Finished sleeping
END OnMouseDown
```

Comment: You can check this [link](https://javascript.info/mouse-events-basics#events-order) for events order sequence. Also it will be good if you post with some codes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the question and added code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by:

- implementing a sleep based on [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/delay-sleep-pause-wait/)
- introducing a flag *onMouseDownStillProcessing* that is set to false/true at the beginning/end of OnMouseDown, respectively.
- waiting in the beginnning of *OnMouseUp* for *onMouseDownStillProcessing* to become true.

Answer (score 0):

You can try async await,
Define an async function then use await keyword on the mouswdown event, it will not fire the next event untill the the async function is done

Comment: I don't think async/await would solve my problem. The nousedown mouseup events are and should be kept indipendent.

Answer (score 0):

What i'm understanding is that you want to record events in the sequence they have fired.
Please check this solution:

```js
// The mousedown event is fired when a pointing device button (usually a mouse button) is pressed on an element.
var ismousedown = false;
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ismousedown = true;
    console.log('BEG OnMouseDown');
});


// The mouseup event is fired when a pointing device button (usually a mouse button) is released over an element.
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(ismousedown){
    ismousedown = false;
    console.log('BEG OnMouseUp');
    }
});
```

Is this what you're looking for? There is something else i have missed?

Comment: Please mark the answer if your question has been resolved. Thanks!